# Local and Global Invertibility

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse, jacobian

Let f: $R^{2}$ -> $R^{2}$ be given by:
f(x,y):= \begin{pmatrix} x^{4} + y^{4} \\ 4xy\end{pmatrix}

1. Show that f is locally invertible in any point of the line in $R^{2}$ defined by the equation 2y = x .
2. Is f globally invertible? Show working

How would one solve such questions. Can someone please give a detailed working to clear up my concept.

Comment: Do you understand the notions of local and global invertibility? Which part is troubling you?

Comment: Local invertibility is linked to the determinant of the jacobian I presume and global is linked to injectivity. This is somewhat I understand but I can't seem to solve this question.

Comment: $f$ is not locally invertible along the line specified. Are you instead asking whether the restriction of $f$ to this domain is invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Local Invertibility**

Local invertibility refers to whether the *closest affine approximation* to $f$ at a given point $(x,y)$ is invertible. The closest affine approximation to $f$ at a point $(x,y)$ is given by $f(x,y)$ plus the derivative of $f$, otherwise known as the Jacobian in this case.

Denote $f(x,y) = \left(\begin{matrix}
f_1(x,y) \\
f_2(x,y)
\end{matrix}\right)$. Then the Jacobian of $f$ at a point $(a,b)$ is a linear map $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ given by the matrix

$$J(a,b) = \left.\left( \begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}
\end{matrix} \right)\right|_{x=a,y=b}.$$

In this case, it's a straightforward computation to yield

$$J(x,y) = \left( \begin{matrix}
4x^3 & 4y^3 \\
4y & 4x\end{matrix} \right).$$
The question asks whether $f$ is locally invertible along a particular line in its domain defined by $x=2y$. This is equivalent to the Jacobian of $f$ along this line being invertible. How do we test whether a linear map $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is invertible? Just test its determinant!

Substituting $x=2y$ into the Jacobian:
$$J(2y,y) = \left( \begin{matrix}
32y^3 & 4y^3 \\
4y & 8y\end{matrix} \right).$$
Calculating its determinant:
$$\begin{align}\det J(2y,y) &= (32y^3)(8y) - (4y^3)(4y) \\
&=y \left( (32y^2)(8) - (4y^2)(4)\right)
\end{align}$$
...and we stop right there, because we can see that at $y=0$, this determinant is $0$. The map $f$ is in fact *not* locally invertible along the line of the domain $(2y,y)$.

---

**Global Invertibility**

It is easy to see that $f$ is not globally invertible, since it is not an injective map. It is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, meaning that we can swap these parameters and retain the same value of $f$. So pick any non-zero $x$ or $y$ and we find
$$f(x,y) = f(y,x)$$
...meaning that $f$ assigns the same value to two distinct points in its domain.

Comment: Would the function: f(a,b,c)= \begin{pmatrix} asin(b)cos(c) \\ asin(b)sin(c) \\ asin(b) \end{pmatrix} also be globally invertible?